# Php: are magic functions like magic constants: case insensitive?

Tags: php, case-insensitive

On the official manual, you can read that magic constants are case-insensitive:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

I've tested on `__tostring()` and `__toString()` and it's the same = case-insensitive.

There's no documentation about it.

Do you know if **all** magic functions are like magic constants = case insensitive?

Comment: Yes, but that is documented. See the PHP manual about function names, they are all case-insensitive.

Comment: Where? I didn't find something relevant in the official documentation here http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php do you have any that could help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Note:** Function names are case-insensitive, though it is usually good form to call functions as they appear in their declaration.

http://www.php.net/manual/functions.user-defined.php

This has to do how function names are stored in PHP internally. And for some languages (like Turkish) this can even lead to problems:

- [Bug #18556 - Setting locale to 'tr_TR' lowercases class names](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=18556)

---

Variable names on the other hand are case-sensitive:

> The variable name is case-sensitive.

http://php.net/manual/language.variables.basics.php

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all functions on php are case-insensitive